# Compiler error Parma Polyhedra Library: undefined reference to `Parma_Polyhedra_Library::Init::Init()'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, linkage, polyhedra

I downloaded last version gmp and ppl from their official websites and installed well. AFAIS, all of library files are in `/usr/local/lib`. But when I try to compile and run C++ file by including `ppl.hh` header, I get the error,

```
CMakeFiles/CLionProjects.dir/untitled/main.cpp.o: 
In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/usr/local/include/ppl.hh:19804: undefined reference to `Parma_Polyhedra_Library::Init::Init()'
/usr/local/include/ppl.hh:19804: undefined reference to `Parma_Polyhedra_Library::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Contents of `/usr/local/lib`,

```
soner@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib$ ls
libgmp.a          libgmpxx.la        libppl_c.la        libppl.so.14
libgmp.la         libgmpxx.so        libppl_c.so        libppl.so.14.0.0
libgmp.so         libgmpxx.so.4      libppl_c.so.4      python2.7
libgmp.so.10      libgmpxx.so.4.5.2  libppl_c.so.4.0.0  python3.5
libgmp.so.10.3.2  libppl.a           libppl.la
libgmpxx.a        libppl_c.a         libppl.so
```

Simple C++ file is,

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ppl.hh"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Even if I tried to run it with `set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 ")`
, still appearing same error. [Source](http://www.cs.unipr.it/pipermail/ppl-devel/2004-July/004330.html)

g++ on terminal on Mac OSX

```
Soners-MacBook-Pro:Documents soner$ g++ -c main.cpp 
Soners-MacBook-Pro:Documents soner$ g++ -o test main.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Parma_Polyhedra_Library::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init.6 in main-d99d55.o
  "Parma_Polyhedra_Library::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init.6 in main-d99d55.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation
```

g++ on Ubuntu

```
soner@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ cat main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "ppl.hh"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
soner@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ g++ -c main.cpp 
soner@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ g++ -o test main.cpp
/tmp/ccQTNpxj.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `Parma_Polyhedra_Library::Init::Init()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `Parma_Polyhedra_Library::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What about `g++ -o test main.cpp -lgmp -lppl -lstdc++` ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent It helps! and acutally only `-lppl` is enough to work (for me).